# Difficulties isolating provided data in Python

Tags: python

I made a python cleaning program to take iOS serial numbers with any unwanted syntax around them, clean them, then re-format them for our internal software. iOS serial numbers have 12 characters and are uppercase like 'GG7ZX449MF3M'. However, with this program, if the serial numbers are not isolated by either a space, or the have a lowercase character from syntax next to them, they will be seen by the program as junk and deleted.

Is there a better way to isolate serial numbers than what I'm doing below given the parameters for serial numbers?

It takes input like the following:

```
("common.SerialNumber" =  "GG7FQ5B5Q1GF"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "GG7C30DEMF3M"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "DMPFQGA0LM93"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "DLXYV7TFLM93"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "GG7C2RQXMF3M"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "GG7C31PFMF3M"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "GG7C42DYMF3M"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "GG7ZX0L2MF3M"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "GG7C30MUMF3M"  X1IZDSNZZFAD6ZPM980MSGRBJSU2VUBTOFFANMNFZPE7X1Q11QJEWRJSIPW3PJX06J4NC6LUA3GJP2OUZI6HL9FBPJWG7AY4LF68LHQRVL682P00RAUNLNJZHC5A44JZYDAPP4HVNPHI4E6PY3WDQIXQMSTZUV5TUYVXUO9K4BBCBEUD1ERLYEVSEFOJRRGP5ZJAANB3I8I74GU5PTQTEAP7
```

And turns it into:

```
("common.SerialNumber" =  "GG7FQ5B5Q1GF"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "GG7C30DEMF3M"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "DMPFQGA0LM93"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "DLXYV7TFLM93"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "GG7C2RQXMF3M"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "GG7C31PFMF3M"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "GG7C42DYMF3M"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "GG7ZX0L2MF3M"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "GG7C30MUMF3M"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "X1IZDSNZZFAD"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "6ZPM980MSGRB"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "JSU2VUBTOFFA"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "NMNFZPE7X1Q1"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "1QJEWRJSIPW3"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "PJX06J4NC6LU"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "A3GJP2OUZI6H"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "L9FBPJWG7AY4"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "LF68LHQRVL68"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "2P00RAUNLNJZ"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "HC5A44JZYDAP"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "P4HVNPHI4E6P"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "Y3WDQIXQMSTZ"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "UV5TUYVXUO9K"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "4BBCBEUD1ERL"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "YEVSEFOJRRGP"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "5ZJAANB3I8I7"  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "4GU5PTQTEAP7") AND "common.retired" = false
```

```py
print("This program will extract any iOS serial numbers from unwanted characters and format it for filtered labels.")
okayish = input('Paste jumbled text here: ')
nonduplicates = []

#removes punctuation and replaces with a space
punc = '''!()-[]{};:'="\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
for e in okayish:
    if e in punc:
        okayish = okayish.replace(e, " ")

#splits all text groups separated by a space into items in a list
okayishwords = okayish.split()

#finds SN that are not separated by spaces
findnospacesn = [e for e in okayishwords if len(e) % 12 == 0 and e.isupper()]

#converts list item to string
thisis = "".join(findnospacesn)
pain = ' '.join(thisis[i:i+12] for i in range(0, len(thisis), 12))
bro = pain.split()

#copies all the words that are all uppercase and have 12 characters to a new list
resultwords = [e for e in okayishwords if len(e) == 12 and e.isupper()]

#removes duplicates - new list
[nonduplicates.append(x) for x in resultwords if x not in nonduplicates]
[nonduplicates.append(x) for x in bro if x not in nonduplicates]

#adds syntax to output
for i in range(len(nonduplicates)):
    nonduplicates[i] = '  OR"common.SerialNumber" =  "'+nonduplicates[i]+'"'

#converts list item to string
result = ''.join(nonduplicates)

#more code is after this, but its only formatting a nice print statement and a little cleanup on the final string
print(result)
```

Comment: Why is `GG7FQ5B5Q1GF` removed from your result?

Comment: It seems like you should be able to do this with a regular expression `\b[A-Z\d]{12}\b`

Comment: @Barmar i did not run that exact statement through when i posted the example. It would.
Can you elaborate on how you would implement `\b[A-Z\d]{12}\b` for me?

Comment: Please show the desired result for that example, so we can see how they relate. It's confusing otherwise.

Comment: Put it in the question, not a comment.

Comment: Just use `re.findall(r'[A-Z\d]{12}', that_string)` to split it up.